# How to export IES file to advance the design?

Tags: led

Our LED luminaries need to sell to US, according to LM-79 and LM-80 request, it
needs to meet energy star request, how to do that test? How to export IES file to advance the design?

Answer (score 0):

LSG-2000 Goniophotometer with Rotating Mirror can achieve the testing program of CIE C-γ、 CIE B- β and CIE A-α, IESNA file format output can be transfered by other illumination and luminaire design software. The test report is according to Energy Start request. The LSG-2000 instruments system is developed understand LM-79 & LM-80. You can download the brochure at: http://www.lisungroup.com/Goniophotometer-with-Rotating-Mirror.pdf